# Beacon Proximity: Is this still a issue from Apple API reference.

Tags: ios, geolocation, ibeacon, ios7.1

We are having a issue with iBeacons.

App makes wrong guess sometimes as to which proximity region its in before eventually correcting itself. It sometimes shows Far when the Proximity is Near. And then later it flips back to Near.

The problem actually occurs when we need to fire an event when we are in the Near/Far/Immediate region. This doest happen in that way. App is likely to lose range of beacons for brief instances.

Are there any other way to solve this Issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for the Proximity estimate to fluctuate with radio noise, but your experience sounds extreme.  What iBeacon brand are you using?

Make sure you are using an iBeacon with as fast enough transmission rate. Different iBeacons transmit advertisements at different frequencies from 30 times per second to once per second or less. Generally, faster transmission rates give you less noisy distance estimates because they give iOS more radio signal strength measurements to work with.

If an iBeacon transmits less than once per sec, you may get intermittent exit/entry events.

For your testing, Try an iOS-based iBeacon like [Locate for iBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8) or [EZBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id842580782?mt=8) to see if it helps. It is known to transmit 30x per second.

Answer (score 0):

The proximity issue can be effected by advertising frequency as David has already said. The reason for this is that iOS takes an average of the RSSI readings overtime and uses these to find a final value, if you hold an iOS device in an ideal location, (i.e. clear line of site to the beacon) the result settles down over a few seconds of holding the device still. Apple describes the averaging as: ["This value is the average RSSI value of the samples received since the range of the beacon was last reported to your app."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeacon_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLBeacon/proximity)

However a bigger factor can be fluctuations in the environment, the RSSI will change dramatically if an obstruction appears between the iBeacon and the iOS device, if the iBeacon and iOS device are both at a low level, this could be a person walking past. [I have published some initial results using Estimote iBeacons that show changes in distance based on the device operator rotating 360 degrees.](http://bitly.com/1oh8Vfa) A distance change of +/- 2m is not an uncommon change in this circumstance and could result in the behaviour you observed if the iOS device is near the proximity region boundary.

Answer (score 0):

This is Wojtek Borowicz, I'm a community evangelist at Estimote.

Calculating the exact proximity of a Beacon is based solely on the radio waves it’s broadcasting an is really hard. You encounter factors like multipath propagation, wave diffraction, absorption or interference. That’s exactly why iBeacon standard does not try to calculate the exact distance between a Beacon and the receiving device. Instead, it uses a value called RSSI (received signal strength indicator), which allows to estimate the proximity based on signal power. For calibration purposes, there’s also included a metric called Measured Power - but it’s nothing more than just RSSI measured 1 meter away from the Beacon. Even calibrated, RSSI might fluctuate heavily, due to the factors mentioned above.

The stability of the Beacon’s signal is also based on two main factors. One of them is advertising interval (frequency - the lower, the better signal) and broadcasting power (the higher the better signal). Improving them will allow for much better proximity reading, but will also strongly affect battery life.